# How can I use "onchange" to get immediate response?

Tags: javascript, events

I'd like to make visible the event, event.target objects and  show immediately how event.target.value changes when I type in an input field.

My code works but it only shows the things when I click next to the input field.

Is it possible to show the value of event.target.value property as I am typing in?

(Here is the full version:
https://codepen.io/parragiWeb/pen/mdPREoB)

Here is part of it:

HTML: `<input id="elem" type="text"></input>`

JS:

```
elem.onchange = (event) => {
  for(let key in event) {
    output.innerHTML += "<p>" + key + ": " +  event[key] +"</p>";
  }
  
  for(let key in event.target) {
    output2.innerHTML += "<p>" + key + ": " +  event[key]  + "</p>";
  }
  
  output3.innerHTML += "<p>" + event.target.value + "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event should be `onkeyup`. This works fine now. Hope it helps!!.. Happy Coding!!

```js
let output = document.getElementById("output");
output.innerHTML = "<span class='head'><b>event</b> object properties and values:</span>";

let output2 = document.getElementById("output2");
output2.innerHTML = "<span class='head'><b>event.target</b> object properties and values:</span>";

let output3 = document.getElementById("output3");
output3.innerHTML = "<span class='head'><b>event.target.value</b>:</span>";

elem.onkeyup= (event) => {
  for(let key in event) {
    output.innerHTML += "<p>" + key + ": " +  event[key] +"</p>";
  }
  
  for(let key in event.target) {
    output2.innerHTML += "<p>" + key + ": " +  event[key]  + "</p>";
  }
  
  output3.innerHTML += "<p>" + event.target.value + "</p>";
}
```

```css
.objs{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
#output3{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
.head {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.clearfix {
  margin-bottom: 20px;  
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
<p>Type in the input field and then click next to it. </p>
<p>"When an event happens, the browser creates an event object, puts details into it and passes it as an argument to the handler." <a href="https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events#event-object" target="blank"> (javascript.info)</a></p>
<label for="elem">Input field: </label>
<input id="elem" type="text"></input>
</div>
<div class="objs" id="output"></div>
<div class="objs" id="output2"></div>
<div id="output3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Do you know why onchange does not work this way?

Comment: onchange` event will be triggered only when the input box's control goes out of focus, but `onkeyup` or `onkeypress` events will work whenever a key is pressed.  Hope this helps!! @ZoltánParragi

Answer (score 0):

The proper event to use is the `input` event, since that also triggers when you keep pressing down a key (and no keyup event occurs), or when you use the context menu to change text, or drag/drop a text, or use another input device...

I would also filter the content you output, as function objects and plain objects do not print well. Also, when a property has a HTML string, it should be escaped.

Here is how it could be done:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let output = document.querySelector("#output");
let output1 = document.querySelector("#output1");
let output2 = document.querySelector("#output2");

input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    function html(obj) {
        const list = [];
        for (let key in obj) {;
            if (!["function","object"].includes(typeof obj[key]) && key !== key.toUpperCase()) {
                list.push(`${key}: ${JSON.stringify(obj[key]).replace(/</g, "&lt;")}`);
            }
        }
        return list.join("<br>\n");
    }
    
    output.innerHTML = html(event);
    output1.innerHTML = html(event.target);
    output2.textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100% }
th, td { border: 1px solid; }
td:nth-child(2) { width: 50% }
```

```html
<input>
<p>

<table><tr><th>event</th><th>event.target</th><th>event.target.value</th></tr>
<tr valign="top"><td id="output"></td><td id="output1"></td><td id="output2"></td></tr>
</table>
```